# How do I parse an x509 certificate and extract its key's signature algorithm?

Tags: ios, ssl, x509certificate, tls1.3, security-framework

I have an x509 certificate as a file/byte array that I'd like to use to verify the signature provided in a `CertificateVerify` TLS message. I think I can use [`SecKeyVerifySignature`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1643715-seckeyverifysignature) once I've determined the certificate's key algorithm (`SecKeyAlgorithm` parameter) and initialized the `signedData` from the [transcript hash](https://tlswg.org/tls13-spec/draft-ietf-tls-tls13.html#the-transcript-hash) (concatenated to the context string, etc.).

`openssl x509` reports the certificate's key like

```
Subject Public Key Info:
    Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
        Public-Key: (256 bit)
        pub:
            04:44:58:8c:d0:95:90:14:45:82:db:4f:56:41:7d:
            57:0e:f5:b4:d8:65:04:6c:21:5a:cd:1e:0e:87:10:
            f9:31:c6:fa:b9:ad:b3:a5:e1:df:9f:32:25:4b:a9:
            40:5c:d4:56:0d:bb:55:fd:f4:68:f9:4e:89:70:56:
            b9:1c:4a:ef:93
        ASN1 OID: prime256v1
        NIST CURVE: P-256
```

I believe I can parse the certificate with the mechanism described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/certificates/storing_a_der-encoded_x_509_certificate?language=objc), eg.

```
CFDataRef certData = CFDataCreate(NULL, (const UInt8*) rawCert, len);
SecCertificateRef certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certData);
```

And I think I can use [`SecCertificateCopyKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/2963103-seccertificatecopykey?language=objc) to extract the key, eg.

```
SecKeyRef key = SecCertificateCopyKey(certificate);
```

I can't, however, find a way to extract the key's signature algorithm (Public Key Algorithm). I found [`SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1644057-seckeyisalgorithmsupported). Do I need to iterate over al the possible `SecKeyAlgorithm` constants to find the one that the key is using (ie. a `SecKeyAlgorithm` for `id-ecPublicKey`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood my own goals.

The `CertificateVerify` message provides a digest of the handshake up to that point. The server uses its certificate's private key to perform that signature. As indicated in [the TLS 1.3 specification](https://tlswg.org/tls13-spec/draft-ietf-tls-tls13.html#rfc.section.4.4.3), the signature algorithm is part of the CertificateVerify structure

```
struct {
    SignatureScheme algorithm;
    opaque signature<0..2^16-1>;
} CertificateVerify;
```

I just need to extract it and convert it to a `SecKeyAlgorithm`. For example (with C++)

```
SecKeyAlgorithm keyAlgorithm;
// algorithm extracted from CertificateVerify
switch (algorithm) {
  case SignatureScheme::ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256:
    keyAlgorithm = kSecKeyAlgorithmECDSASignatureDigestX962SHA256;
    break;
  case SignatureScheme::rsa_pss_sha256:
    keyAlgorithm = kSecKeyAlgorithmRSASignatureDigestPSSSHA256;
    break;
  case SignatureScheme::ed25519:
  case SignatureScheme::ed448:
  default:
    throw std::runtime_error("unsupported peer cert type");
}
```

I can then confirm the certificate supports that algorithm

```
if (!SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(key, kSecKeyOperationTypeVerify, keyAlgorithm)) {
  CFRelease(publicKey);
  throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported signature scheme");
}
```

and finally perform the verification with the `signature` in the `CertificateVerify` and the compiled signed data from the handshake

```
CFErrorRef error;
bool signatureVerified = SecKeyVerifySignature(key, keyAlgorithm, toBeSignedData, signature, &error);
if (!signatureVerified) {
  CFRelease(error); // or use it
  throw std::runtime_error("Signature verification failed");
}
```